# SaaS Architecture - Data Contamination

Tags: architecture, multi-tenant, saas

Working with a startup in the home improvement industry.  Its a SaaS model - multi-tenant system.  Each account is uniquely identified and all customers, projects, and other data are identified using the unique account number.  We are using a MVC framework and the queries use the session of the account when the user logs in.  As we continue to grow I constantly rethink what I have done - concerned about cross contamination and other multi-tenant issues.

Does anything have any good "Best Practices" links or have gone through what I have done to date?   I consider my concern a good thing as I am aware of the data, structure and whatnot.  I feel its better than not really caring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also work in a company that develops a SaaS product for years.

Your way of thinking is correct.

As long as the data is logically separated by the corresponding unique ID that belongs to a specific user you are on the right path.

You can separate the data by creating a separate database/schema for each of your customers, isolating them one from another.

If you are really concerned about your servers being hacked, then you could try and separate the delicate data in multiple servers so you don't have all your data in one place. That will require more complex maintenance procedures having to update each of the servers for each system update, without even talking about the costs of such an architecture.

You can always expand and create physical separations, where a certain data may be in another database server, but I think that virtually dividing the data is more than OK for most cases - If done right.

Comment: Thanks for the input.   We are not at the size yet where we need multiple servers but will be within a year given the current growth.   I've developed SaaS products in the past where 1 application drives a single-database-per-customer approach and its really nice, but a real pain when the application is changing.   We noticed we ran a greater risk of issues when each database was handled separately.

Comment: Yes it is a real pain, right? I think a centric database will be a good way to begin. Then you can expand from there to other infra structures having plenty of time to research for what you find best suitable for your future needs. Please mark my answer as accepted if you think i helped.